# JSON deserialization with C# problems

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization, primitive

I am having a problem reading the following JSON output in C#.  I am not too familiar with JSON syntax, but it doesn't seem to be properly formatted, or I am unclear how to properly deserialize the data:

> Array (
>       [label] => Column_Name
>       [column] => column0 )
>
> 15 0
>
> Array (
>       [0] => 0
>       [1] => Array
>           (
>           )
>
> ```
> [2] => 0 ) {"total":0,"entities":[],"page":0}
> ```

The code used in C# is simply:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
request.Accept = "application/json";
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
StreamReader configStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), enc);
var configuration = configStream.ReadToEnd();
JavaScriptSerializer jSerialize = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List[] operations = jSerialize.Deserialize<List[]>(configuration);
```

The error I am receiving is that 'Array' is not a valid JSON primitive.  Assuming the syntax *is* correct from the JSON output, how do I derialize the data?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work for correct JSON input. The only part of your input that's correct json is: `{"total":0,"entities":[],"page":0}`

Answer (score 0):

In one of my Silverlight project I've do this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json; //add this library to refferences

ObservableCollection<MyClass> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<MyClass>>(json)
```

Hope this help.